# rsync file in ansible playbook retaining the ownership

Tags: ansible

I am trying to install elasticsearch using ansible playbook and able to to install it successfully. But unable to update the configuration files `/etc/default/elasticsearch` and `/etc/elasticsearch/elastisearch.yml`. Both of these files have ownership `root:elasticsearch`due to which getting the error `Permission denied`

Following is the playbook

```
- name: copying the elasticsearch configuration
    synchronize:
      src: /mnt/"{{ item.source }}"
      dest: "{{ item.desti }}"
    with_items:  
      - { source: 'elasticsearch.service', desti: '/usr/lib/systemd/system/' }
      - { source: 'limits.conf', desti: '/etc/security/' } 

  - name: copying the elasticsearch configuration
    synchronize:
      src: /mnt/"{{ item.source }}"
      dest: "{{ item.desti }}"
    with_items:  
      - { source: 'elasticsearch', desti: '/etc/default/' }
      - { source: 'elasticsearch.yml', desti: '/etc/elasticsearch/' }
```

Could anyone please help me how do I copy the config file from source to destination

Comment: It appears your playbook or these tasks are missing `become: yes`; do you have that keyword on your playbook or are you using `--become` when running `ansible-playbook`?

Comment: yes, I have set it for the playbook as below                                                                   ```-  hosts: es_master_node
   remote_user: ansible
   become: yes```

Comment: are you sure you aren't getting this error on the local files? in your ansible master the user running the playbook has the right permissions?

Comment: ansible is the user running the playbook and it has root privileges

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Files have ownership root:elasticsearchdue to which getting the error Permission denied."*

A: Make sure to [become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation-become) root. For example

```
- command: whoami
  register: result
- debug:
    var: result.stdout
```

should give

```
"result.stdout": "root"
```